# How do I find the inverse of $y=2x^2+2x+2$

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

I'm supposed to find the inverse of $$y=2x^2+2x+2 $$
I know that the inverse isn't a function, as it isn't injective, but we're supposed to find it in domain $[0, 1]$.
So far, I've switched x for y, and tried to solve for y, and gotten so far:
$$ x=2y^2+2y+2$$
$$ 2y^2 + 2y = x-2$$
$$ y(y+1)=1/2 (x-2)$$

WolframAlpha tells me the inverse is supposed to be
$$ y= 1/2 (\pm\sqrt{2x-3}-1 ) $$
But I have no idea how to get so far

Comment: It's a quadradic equation so you just use the formula or complete the square.

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: Draw using for example Geogebra the curve of $y=2x^2+2x+2$. Reflect the curve with respect to the diagonal with equation $y=x$. What do you observe ? Now draw the curve with equation $y= 1/2 (+\sqrt{2x-3}-1 )$. What do you observe ?

Comment: You do have for the parabola $y=2x^2+2x+2$ two regions on which you can find out  the inverse. These are where the restricted function is bijective (only case in which $y=f(x)$ and $x=f^{-1}(y)$ have sens.)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, one should use the quadratic formula. To see this, transform your initial equation in the following:

$$ x = 2y^2 + 2y + 2 \Leftrightarrow 0 = y^2 + y + \left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right).$$

Using the usual quadratic formula in this, we get:

$$y = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1-4\left(\frac{2-x}{2}\right)}}{2} = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1-4+2x}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \pm \sqrt{2x-3} - 1\right).$$

Confirming the result your obtained through WolframAlpha.

Comment: Thanks a lot, using x as constant wasnt so stupid, it was the most confusing part for me.